# Is there any nonconstant function that grows (at infinity) slower than all iterations of the (natural) logarithm?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, asymptotics

Is there any nonconstant function that grows at infinity slower than all iterations of the (natural) logarithm?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, just take a function which is equal to $\log x$ on an initial interval such as $[1,K_1]$, then equal to $\log\log x$ on the interval $(K_1,K_2]$, then $\log\log\log x$ etc. where the values $K_1, K_2, \dots$ are chosen sufficiently large to ensure that the function really does tend to infinity. This can always be done, since each of the iterations of the log function does tend to infinity.

This function will not be continuous, but a similar function could certainly be created which is continuous.

This will produce a function which tends to infinity slower than any (fixed) iteration of $\log$. If you want something even slower, then call my function above $\phi (x)$, and repeat my construction using $\phi\phi(x)$ etc on successive intervals.

If this is still not slow enough, then ...

Comment: I suspect a smooth one could be created, and maybe G. H. Hardy's old book "Orders of Infinity" might be worth a look.

Comment: @Frank: my answer gives a continuous one, and it would not be difficult to smooth the kinks

Comment: @Frank Hardy's book is available (legally) [here on Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38079), and although a bit old-fashioned (like me) it is still worth a read.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful reference.

Comment: @Frank: smoothing the kinks was easier than I expected.

Comment: Are you certain this tends to infinity?

Comment: As it stands in the way I have suggested choosing the intervals, no, it doesn't! It can easily be corrected, though, by taking the successive intervals sufficiently long. I will post a corrected solution ...

Comment: @BrunoJoyal: Those are the same thing. It'd be different if the solution provided different functions for different numbers of iterations, but a function growing slower than any iteration is the same as it growing slower than all iterations.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right. I was thrown off by the wording. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Let $\text{LogNestMonster}_i(n) = nest(log, i)(n) = \overbrace{log(log(...(log}^\text{i times}(n))...))$.

Many functions grow slower than $\text{LogNestMonster}_i$, no matter how large the $i$ you picked is:

1. The [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse) $\alpha$ grows slower than all $\text{LogNestMonster}$s. It (roughly) tells you how far in the sequence $1+1$, $2 \cdot 2$, $3^3$, $4\uparrow\uparrow4$, $5\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow5$, $...$ you have to go before exceeding $n$.
2. The [iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) $log^*$ also grows slower than all $\text{LogNestMonster}$s. It counts how many times you have to apply log to $n$ before the result is less than $1$.
3. Also, consider the function $\frac{1}{n}$. It is not constant and is clearly asymptotically less than all $\text{LogNestMonster}$s, although I'm guessing it's not exactly what you had in mind since $\frac{1}{n}$ is $O(1)$ despite not being $\Theta(1)$.

Comment: @Frank It seems like a reasonable answer to me...

Comment: 1/n is decreasing. I think the OP wants an increasing function.

Comment: @martycohen The answer mentions that already.

Comment: I haven't seen the `nest` function before and I'm interested in learning more. It's a bit hard to search for though, can you point me in the direction of any resources that talk about `nest` from a mathematical point of view?

Comment: @7yl4r [Iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function). I've seen it called "iter" before. I just called it nest for the sake of the pun.

Comment: Thanks @CraigGidney. That's just what I was looking for. Thanks to this tip I also found that the [iterated logarithm is often called log*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm).

Comment: The play on words is hilarious!  (+1!)

Answer (score 13):

In fact there are functions that go to $\infty$ more slowly than any function you can write down a formula for.  For positive integers $n$ let $f(BB(n)) = n$ where $BB$ is the Busy Beaver function.  Extend to $[1,\infty)$ by interpolation.

EDIT: Stated more technically, a "function you can write down a formula for" is a recursive function: it can be computed by a Turing machine.  $BB(n)$ is not recursive, and grows faster than any recursive function.  If $g(n)$ is a recursive (integer-valued, for simplicity), nondecreasing 
function with $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = \infty$, then there is a recursive function $h$ such that for all positive integers $n$, 
$g(h(n)) > n^2$.  Namely, here is an algorithm for calculating $h(n)$ for any positive integer $n$:
 start at $y = 1$ and increment $y$ until $g(y) > n^2$, then output $y$.

Now since $BB$ grows faster than any recursive function, for sufficiently large $n$ (say $n \ge N$) 
we have $BB(n) > h(n+1)$.
For any integer $x \ge h(N)$, there is $n \ge N$ such that $h(n) \le x < h(n+1)$, and then (since $f$ and $g$ are nondecreasing)
$$f(x) \le f(h(n+1)) \le f(BB(n)) = n < \sqrt{g(h(n)} \le \sqrt{g(x)}$$
and thus
$$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{g(x)}} \to 0\ \text{as} \ x \to \infty $$

Comment: This assumes, of course, that "$BB(n)$ doesn't count as a formula.

Comment: What about g(x)=f(x)/2

Comment: @Bulwersator They both have the exact same growth rate at $\infty$. A function $g(x)$ has a smaller growth rate than $f(x)$ at $\infty$ iff $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}} = 0$$ or alternately: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} = \infty$$.

Comment: The [inverse Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse) is frequently cited in these contexts.

Answer (score 7):

Yes:

My favorite big-number function from positive numbers to positive numbers, a continuous variant of Old John's.

Write $log_{10}^{(n)} x$ for the $n$th iterated base 10 logarithm of $x$.

If  $log_{10}^{(n)} x \in [0,1)$ then let $f(x)=n+log_{10}^{(n)} x$.

You can extend this to non-positive numbers with $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ giving a continuous bijective function on the reals.

If you want a smooth function take natural logarithms base $e$ instead

Comment: excellent - thanks!

Comment: Note that a version of this function - 'how many iterations of log does it take to reduce $x$ to $\lt 1$?' - shows up regularly in the analysis of algorithms; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm for details.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:
$$f(x):=\min\{n\geq1\>|\> \log^{\circ n}(x)<0\}\ .$$

Comment: Does this function tent toward infinity at all though? An explanation would be nice.

Comment: @AJMansfield: It's more or less the inverse of $x_0:=0$, $x_{n+1}:=e^{x_n}$ $\>(n\geq0)$.